# Count Name list (mixed with Number)

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the Customer's Name in my data. 
For example, if there are `["Jacob Lee", "Jacob Lee 30220", "30220"]` in the column, I want to count these cases as a same person. Because `30220` is Jacob Lee's account number.

I'm not sure how to code this function.

FYI: I'm using python 3.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and an expected output

Comment: `if val == 'Jacob Lee' or val.startswith('Jacob Lee '):`

Comment: Since you mention a column, I'll assume you're using pandas. Research how to access the values of a column as strings with `col.str` and use the string method `contains`

Comment: Do you know ahead of time which customer you're looking for, i.e. are you asking "Are both of these customers Jacob Lee?"  Or are you asking the more general question "Is _this_ customer the same as _that_ customer?"

Comment: Did my code work?

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of @JohnGordon:

Use `if val == 'Jacob Lee' or val.startswith('Jacob Lee ') or val == '30220' or val.startswith('30220 '):`

Comment: this will not count for `30220` only, as provided in the list

Comment: Hm. Didn't understand the question. How about now?